# Is it possible to represent this controller in a block diagram (a car)?

Tags: control, control-system

I am working on a car in a project. There is something called a lambda-value, which is the relationship between air intake and fuel intake.
$$\lambda = \frac{\text{fuel mass}/\text{air mass}}{(\text{fuel mass}/\text{air mass})_{Stoich}} $$
Anyway, it turns out for the car, the optimal lambda-value is around \$\lambda=1.3 \$. The car can be set such that the injection length of the fuel input to give a lambda-value of 1.3, and this is done by auto-tuning the car. However, the injection length \$t_{inj} \$ for \$\lambda=1.3 \$ changes with temperature, so the car have to be tuned just before a race. It takes a few sweeps of tuning for the car to obtain the proper injection length. \$t_{inj} \$ is "tuned" with this formula.
$$t_{inj} = t_{inj,old}+(\lambda_{desired}-\lambda_{measured})\cdot K_p $$
where \$t_{inj,old} \$ is the injection length of the sweep before, and \$K_p \$ is a correction factor - so it is a simple P-controller we have here.

**Note** that the input is \$\lambda_{desired} \$ and the output is \$t_{inj} \$.

My question is, if it is possible to represent this formula in a block diagram, so it can be used in Simulink? The main problem is that \$t_{inj,old} \$ is used, and it seems like one would need a shift register to remember the earlier value.

I thought of something like this below, but I know it can't be right, because \$t_{inj,old} \$ is not the same as the reference.

[image]

Comment: Does simulink have a delay block?

Comment: By "old" do you mean value in a previous simulation or value in current simulation at an earlier time instant? It is also not clear if the update equation is discrete time or continuous time equation.

Comment: @AJN I mean the value of the previous simulation. So if I wanted to find a transfer function, I guess I could only find it discretely, right?

Comment: I don't have access to simulink now, but it should be possible to export the value to **workspace**. So that, during next simulation run, you can load it from workspace. Workspace or  filewrite: this is how I make simulink remember values *between* simulations.

Comment: "*So if I wanted to find a transfer function, I guess I could only find it discretely, right?*". I don't fully understand the stated problem. So I can't comment on that.

Comment: Why do you want this single update formula for t_inj in a simulink block? Is it not easy enough to code in matlab? Let me see if i understood the problem correctly: there is a complex simulink diagram already made which simulates a car engine. It gives \$\lambda_{measured}\$ after running for some time duration. Now you want to re run the engine simulation with a new value of t_inj. Did i understand the problem correctly? So the t_inj needs to be updated only after running the car block for quite some time.

Comment: My first instinct would be to use zero order hold blocks (with a very high sampling time period) at strategic locations to ensure that t_inj is updated with large time gaps in between updates as compared to the car simulation block

Comment: @AJN Sorry for the poorly formulated question. The problem I am facing, is that it takes many sweeps for the car to reach \$\lambda_{desired} \$, and I assume this is because we use a simple P-controller. I want to find the transfer function between \$\lambda_{measured}\$ and \$\lambda_{desired}\$ such that I can design a better controller such that it doesn't take that many sweeps for the car to be properly tuned. But perhaps I don't need a block diagram to do that?

Comment: I think you are basically asking for a transfer for the car engine model effectively. That depends on the complexity of the car engine model. So, if you received the transfer function you wanted, you won't have to simulate the car engine for tuning the t_inj

Comment: What's a "sweep before"? Can you evaluate the process of measuring t_inj_old? It's not clear if this value is static or what else? Further, the feedforward path isn't correct, it has to have some conversion units constants or look up table - LUT, many of them temperature, RPM, ...

Comment: @MarkoBuršič When tuning the car, the wheels starts at 0 RPM. Then the RPM steadily increase up to 4000 RPM. The RPM's are split up in intervals, so the interval 0-250RPM has an average lambda-value, 250-500RPM has an average lambda-value, 500-750RPM has an average and so on. This average lambda-value is calculated from the injection length. After one sweep, every RPM interval has an average lambda-value stored, which means that every RPM interval has an injection length stored. The car then checks if all of the average lambda-values are close to 1.3, if not, then it does another *sweep*.

Comment: And this is were the t_inj_old is coming from. It is from the sweep before, so it is not a static value. I know that the block diagram with the feedforward is wrong, but it was only meant as a sketch of how I think it should look like.

Comment: @Carl Yes, it's a static value, a LUT.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should look like. You compute the t by interpolating data from LUT (Look Up Table) that has RPM value as input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcDHwN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:

You can Google : "how to use lookup table in simulink" you may have multiple input variables, 2D, 3D, 4D,...LUT. But more precisely, the t VS. RPM is with little use, the correct approach would be using MAF (Mass Air Flow) sensor which gives the output according to air pressure, temperature and throttle position.

[2D LUT t_injecion VS. (RPM, Throttle position)](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099.1/4143/PFC+Sebastien+ARAB.pdf;jsessionid=F7FFFAB108527F8AD08CDF030FDA1D54?sequence=1)

[image]